# Elasticsearch snapshot restore throwing "repository missing" exception

Tags: amazon-s3, elasticsearch, snapshot, elasticsearch-plugin

```
"error": "RemoteTransportException[[Francis Underwood][inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]][cluster/snapshot/get]]; nested: RepositoryMissingException[[xxxxxxxxx] missing]; ",
   "status": 404
```

I am also unable to create new snapshot repository for snapshots on s3

```
    PUT _snapshot/bkp_xxxxx_master
    {
    "type": "s3",
    settings": {
    "region": "us-xxxx-x",
    "bucket": "elasticsearch-backups",
    "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
```

Response I receive for this PUT is below:

```
    {
   "error": "RemoteTransportException[[Francis Underwood][inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]][cluster/repository/put]]; nested: RepositoryException[[bkp_xxxxxxx_master] failed to create repository]; nested:'AbstractMethodError[org.elasticsearch.cloud.aws.blobstore.S3BlobStore.immutableBlobContainer(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/BlobPath;)Lorg/elasticsearch/common/blobstore/ImmutableBlobContainer;]; ",
   "status": 500
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the S3 Plugin? Maybe this will help you https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws#s3-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old issue but I had been able to replicate this over multiple ElasticSearch versions and it turns out that the reason was **conflict between JVM versions and elasticsearch-aws-cloud plugin versions.**

As long as you have consistent versions across the cluster (in my case it was Joda version in elasticsearch-aws-cloud was not compatible with the latest JVM version I had installed on the newer nodes.